# Stocked certificate issued to a company

Tags: stocks, share-certificate

I have a stock certificate stamped and signed from 1962. The company is still open today but it is issued to another big company. It was passed down to me years ago but doing research on it I can't seem to find out if it was issued to my family. Being that it's not issued to a person to prove inheritance can i do anything with it. I may like to think it was a gift from the issued company.

Comment: Have you asked the "other big company" if they have a record of it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it. A stock certificate which has no endorsement on it is a bearer stock:

> A bearer stock certificate is a negotiable instrument without endorsement which is transferred upon delivery. Someone who has physical possession of the stock certificate in bearer form is entitled to exercise all legal rights associated with the stock. Dividends are payable upon presentation of dividend coupons, which are dated or numbered. Most jurisdictions now require corporations to maintain records of ownership or transfers of shareholdings, and do not permit share certificates to be issued to bearer.

Transfer agent information is necessary to perform the transaction if the company is publicly traded:

> Publicly traded companies use transfer agents to manage individuals and organizations who own shares of their stock. Usually, the transfer agent is a bank or trust company. Sometimes a very large company, like Walt Disney, acts as its own transfer agent. Transfer agents perform three main functions: issuing and canceling stock certificates; acting as an intermediary for the company to pay out interest and stock dividends; and handling lost or destroyed stock certificates.

**References**

- [3 Ways to Sell Stock Certificates - wikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Sell-Stock-Certificates)
- [Transparency of Share Ownership (pdf)](https://www.computershare.com/News/TransparencyofShareOwnershipShareholderCommunicationsandVotinginglobalcapitalmarkets_12032014_GCM.pdf)